# Most compatible 32-64 channel multiplexer for raspberry pi

Tags: i2c, sensor, spi, input-device

I have been working on one sensor testing project. In this project, I have to detect or sense more than 60 sensors at a time with raspberry. I am looking for the most compatible 32 channel multiplexer with a raspberry pi so that I can find the library easily. Could anyone suggest me best multiplexer and it would be great if you inform me of its import library also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are we supposed to guess what you are multiplexing? ... your question is similar to `what is the best tool for the job?` ... see? no information

Comment: @Rikin Tailor, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see, usually sensors themselves have onboard mux for 8 single ended channels, you can also use 3 hardware onboard addr pins to scale up to 64 channels. Some sensors has 1-wire interface and needs only one GPIO pin fo 12+ channels. Rpi4B has 5 I2c and SPI buses so another scaling up trick. For UART, you can use USB to serial adapters, so have "unlimited" serial ports each handlea multiple sensors.  In short you can use any combination above to handle 1,000+ sensors.  You can also digital mux chip and analog mux or GPIO expanders. Cheers.

Comment: @jsotola I apologize for the confusion. I have digital pressure sensors. I have a single cable interface with it. As raspberry pi has 28 GPIO pins so I am able to do with that much pin. I have mentioned earlier that I have more than 60 sensors to communicate at same time. for that, I am finding some solution. Based on this, I am looking for the most compatible multiplexer with raspberry pi 4. I have to design it in a minimum budget due to it I cannot go for the ultimate solutions that are available in the market.

Comment: @tifong Nice to meet you. Thank you for your warm welcome. Also thank you for your answer. I would like to add more information question that I have a single cable interface with the sensor. I have to go for a minimum budget so I am looking for a multiplexer solution. Multiplexer definitely with I2C or with SPI.